# Variable decimal place limit in function set by user?

Tags: python

I just started learning python and am currently writing a script that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit and vise versa. I have the main part done but now I want to be able to let the user set the number of decimals displayed in the output... The first function contains my failed attempt and the second is set at 2 decimal places.

```
def convert_f_to_c(t,xx):
c = (t - 32) * (5.0 / 9)
print "%.%f" % (c, xx)

def convert_c_to_f(t):
    f = 1.8 * t + 32
    print "%.2f" % f    


print "Number of decimal places?"
dec = raw_input(">")

print "(c) Celsius >>> Ferenheit\n(f) Ferenheit >>> Celcius"
option = raw_input(">")

if option == 'c':
    cel = int(raw_input("Temperature in Celcius?"))
    convert_c_to_f(cel)

else: 
    fer = int(raw_input("Temperature in Ferenheit?"))
    convert_f_to_c(fer,dec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
num_dec = int(raw_input("Num Decimal Places?")
print "%0.*f"%(num_dec,3.145678923678)
```

in % format strings you can use a `*` for this feature

afaik there is no equivelent method in `'{}'.Format`method

```
>>> import math
>>> print "%0.*f"%(3,math.pi)
3.142
>>> print "%0.*f"%(13,math.pi)
3.1415926535898
>>>
```

Comment: The operation of "%0.*f"%(13, math.pi) is a little confusing to me because the * is defined before the %... any reason why? or just convention.

In my context it becomes
`print "%0.*f" % (xx,c)`

and it works!

thanks

Comment: @AllTheTime1111: Read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). I agree it's not the simplest to understand, but it's in there. Note especially the part about precision (item 5 in the numbered list explaining the conversion specifier).

Comment: ahh thanks eric that makes sense ... but to be fair python.org has retracted that bit about % being depreciated and going away

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> fp=12.3456789
>>> for prec in (2,3,4,5,6):
...    print '{:.{}f}'.format(fp,prec)
... 
12.35
12.346
12.3457
12.34568
12.345679
```

As does this:

```
>>> w=10
>>> for prec in (2,3,4,5,6):
...    print '{:{}.{}f}'.format(fp,w,prec)
... 
     12.35
    12.346
   12.3457
  12.34568
 12.345679
```

And even:

```
>>> align='^'
>>> for prec in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):
...    print '{:{}{}.{}f}'.format(fp,align,15,prec)
... 
     12.3      
     12.35     
    12.346     
    12.3457    
   12.34568    
   12.345679   
  12.3456789   
  12.34567890  
 12.345678900
```

Before it gets too hairy with automatic field selection, you can use manual too and swap the fields around:

```
>>> for prec in (2,3,4,5,6):
...    print '{2:{0}.{1}f}'.format(w,prec,fp)
... 
     12.35
    12.346
   12.3457
  12.34568
 12.345679
```

The best documentation is really in PEP [3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)